# why isn’t all the output (`stdout` and `stderr`) redirected?

Tags: bash, pipe, io-redirection, stdout

I have some understanding of how the `stdout` and `stderr` file descriptors work. But sometimes they don’t catch all the output and I trying to understand why.
For example, cloning into a git repo gives the following output:

```bash
$ git clone git@github.com:Alex23rodriguez/MyRepo
Cloning into 'MyRepo'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 438, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (438/438), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (319/319), done.
remote: Total 438 (delta 96), reused 410 (delta 68), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (438/438), 13.09 MiB | 1.73 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (96/96), done.
```

but redirecting both `stdout` and `stderr` to a file gives unexpected results

```bash
$ git clone git@github.com:Alex23rodriguez/MyRepo &> log
(no output)
$ cat log
Cloning into 'MyRepo'...
```

My question is, what happened to the rest of the printed lines?

Comment: From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32685644/13594705): You should use `git clone --progress` to be able to get the full output. Also it seems you can use `unbuffer git clone https://....`

Answer (score 4):

They were simply never printed: `git` probably simply checks whether the `stdout` and `stderr` file descriptors are ttys, and if not, it omits the pretty print verbose status updates.

Comment: thanks! I didn't know programs could check if they were being piped. My question wasn't specifically about `git clone` but now it makes sense.

Comment: @alex23ro  Even `ls` uses this trick, in respect of number of columns, and of colourising. Try `ls` versus `ls | cat`.

Comment: Hey @ilkkachu! Thanks for the (saving me) edit :) I'll going to revert one single word, for pedantism reasons, hope you'll not be sad :)